# Keyboard shortcut to move to the end of the document, including endnote pages

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

To move to the end of the document, I can use Ctrl+End, but it stops before the first page used by Writer for endnotes. Is there a keyboard shortcut to move to the **real** end of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"real end" - well that's sort of what it does. Endnotes are not part of the document body; they are separate, like headers and footers. You can see this by going just before the endnotes and then pressing the right arrow key - it won't navigate any further.

If the cursor is just before an endnote superscript in the document, press [Ctrl + Shift + PageDown](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/ar/text/swriter/guide/footnote_usage.html) to go to the endnote.

To go to the final page no matter where the cursor is positioned, use [Ctrl + G](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/is-there-a-goto-page-function/20190/2) (which is *Edit > Go to page*) and enter the physical page number. Conveniently, the last page seems to be the default, because you can press some number keys until it gets past the maximum, or else backspace, and it will stop at the highest possible number.

Comment: That question and answers there are from 2014, and according to the issue tracker itself, this bug is fixed (https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75137). But pressing Ctrl+Shift+PageDown after Ctrl+End still doesn't make any effect for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: That is my experience as well, which is why I wrote that it doesn't work. However it does go to footnotes when the cursor is anywhere on the current page. The bug you linked to is about arrow keys between footnotes, which worked for me.

Comment: Okay, I got the key combination to work for endnotes, and edited the answer accordingly.